# How to build vpxenc.exe in Windows with Cygwin?

Tags: windows, cygwin, libvpx

I have cloned the [libvpx repository](https://github.com/webmproject/libvpx/) on the v1.6.1 tag, and attempted to build it in Windows system with Cygwin.

**Cygwin packages:**

```
make,automake,gcc,gcc-g++,perl,yasm
```

**Cygwin build commands:**

```
$ ../libvpx/configure --disable-examples --disable-install-docs --disable-unit-tests --disable-shared --enable-static --disable-vp9 --target=x86_64-win64-gcc
$ make
```

The build was successful, but I do not see `vpxenc.exe` anywhere. For the record, here's the build folder contents.

```
06/13/2017  03:08 AM    <DIR>          .
06/13/2017  03:08 AM    <DIR>          ..
06/13/2017  03:08 AM                 0 .bins
06/13/2017  03:07 AM                 0 .docs
06/13/2017  03:08 AM                 0 .install-bins
06/13/2017  03:08 AM                 0 .install-docs
06/13/2017  03:08 AM                 0 .install-libs
06/13/2017  03:08 AM                 0 .install-srcs
06/13/2017  03:08 AM                 0 .libs
06/13/2017  03:06 AM            16,885 config.log
06/13/2017  03:06 AM             1,017 config.mk
06/13/2017  03:07 AM             1,909 docs-x86_64-win64-gcc.mk
06/13/2017  03:07 AM             1,909 libs-x86_64-win64-gcc.mk
06/13/2017  03:08 AM         1,737,860 libvpx.a
06/13/2017  03:08 AM         1,744,534 libvpx_g.a
06/13/2017  03:07 AM            14,330 Makefile
06/13/2017  03:08 AM    <DIR>          tools
06/13/2017  03:07 AM             1,909 tools-x86_64-win64-gcc.mk
06/13/2017  03:07 AM    <DIR>          vp8
06/13/2017  03:07 AM            17,414 vp8_rtcd.h
06/13/2017  03:07 AM    <DIR>          vpx
06/13/2017  03:08 AM               305 vpx.pc
06/13/2017  03:07 AM             1,836 vpx_config.asm
06/13/2017  03:07 AM               639 vpx_config.c
06/13/2017  03:07 AM               565 vpx_config.c.d
06/13/2017  03:08 AM               944 vpx_config.c.o
06/13/2017  03:06 AM             2,755 vpx_config.h
06/13/2017  03:07 AM    <DIR>          vpx_dsp
06/13/2017  03:07 AM            91,117 vpx_dsp_rtcd.h
06/13/2017  03:07 AM    <DIR>          vpx_mem
06/13/2017  03:08 AM    <DIR>          vpx_ports
06/13/2017  03:07 AM    <DIR>          vpx_scale
06/13/2017  03:07 AM             2,384 vpx_scale_rtcd.h
06/13/2017  03:07 AM    <DIR>          vpx_util
06/13/2017  03:07 AM               256 vpx_version.h
```

The [build prerequisites readme](https://chromium.googlesource.com/webm/libvpx/+/master/README) did not state anything on building `vpxenc.exe`. There also seems to be a [discussion](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webm/issues/detail?id=76) on a page with binary downloads, but it appears that the [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webm/downloads/list) is dead.

I am hoping to build a static binary of `vpxenc.exe` for another project. Did I miss an argument? Are my build steps wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried fiddling with the configure flags, and I notice that with `--disable-examples` present, `vpxenc.exe` will not be built. Don't know why its like that though. Once `--disable-examples` flag is removed, `vpxenc.exe` will be present in the build directory once the build is completed.

Also, it appears that building a static binary of `vpxenc.exe` with Cygwin is not possible, since building it with Cygwin will form a dependency on Cygwin itself. I had mistaken that I would be able to build a static Windows binary with Cygwin.

As a note, the following Cygwin DLL files will be required by `vpxenc.exe` when executed.

```
/cygdrive/c/cygwin-root/bin/cygwin1.dll
/cygdrive/c/cygwin-root/bin/cygstdc++-6.dll
/cygdrive/c/cygwin-root/bin/cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll
```